# Programmatically Create a Business Data Content Source

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, bcs

I have the need to programmatically define a business data content source in Sharepoint 2010 using C# 2010.  I've reviewed ways to do this from within Central Admin, and have seen snippets from MOSS 2007.  However, I've not located examples of doing this in SP 2010.  Can anyone steer me in the proper direction?

Thanks much for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.toddbaginski.com/blog/archive/2009/11/05/how-to-create-a-searchable-sharepoint-2010-bdc-.net-assembly-connector-which-reads-from-a-flat-file.aspx) should help you.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Answer (score 3):

Using the API

```
        string strURL = "http://mySiteUrl";
        SearchContext searchContext;
        using (SPSite searchSite = new SPSite(strURL))
        {
            searchContext = SearchContext.GetContext(searchSite);
        }
        Content sspContent = new Content(searchContext);
        ContentSourceCollection sspContentSources = sspContent.ContentSources;
        BusinessDataContentSource bdcs = (BusinessDataContentSource)sspContentSources.Create(typeof(BusinessDataContentSource), "MyBdcContentSource");
        bdcs.StartAddresses.Add(BusinessDataContentSource.ConstructStartAddress("Default", new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"), "LOBSystemName", "LOBSystemInstanceName"));
```

Using Powershell

```
$searchapp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "My Search Service Application Name"
$lobSystems = @("LOBSystemName1","LOBSystemNameInstance1")
$proxyGroup = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup -default
New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -name "My Content Source Name" -searchapplication $searchApp -Type Business -LOBSystemSet $lobSystems -BDCApplicationProxyGroup $proxyGroup
```